# PHP regex content between tags with square brackets

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex that will give me everything that appears between `[start-flashcards]` and `[end-flashcards]`

I am using `\[start-flashcards\](.*?)\[end-flashcards\]` but this doesn't match. I must be missing something?

```
<p>[start-flashcards]</p>
  <p>[London|This is the capital city of the United Kingdom]</p>
  <p>[Paris|This is the capital city of France]</p>
  <p>[Madrid|This is the capital city of Spain]</p>
  <p>[Tokyo|This is the capital city of Japan]</p>
  <p>[Moscow|This is the capital city of Russia]</p>
<p>[end-flashcards]</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this:

`\[start-flashcards\]([\s\S]*?)\[end-flashcards\]`

You've used `.`, which doesn't match line-breaks.

EDIT:

Turns out there is an efficient way of achieving the same:

Use your regex `\[start-flashcards\](.*?)\[end-flashcards\]` with the `/s` modifier flag. This flag allows `.` to match newline characters.

Comment: No, do not use `[\s\S]`. It is a work around. Use `.` with `/s` modifier.

Comment: When you say workaround, does it have any side-effects?

Comment: A built-in `.` matches in a more efficient way, faster. Surely not that faster for us to notice, but still...